# how to find a path between two given node in a binary tree

Tags: c++, c, tree, binary-tree

```
if we have a tree given below:



      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \  / \
  4  5 6  7
```

how to find a path between from node 4 to 5 or 4 to 6?
        I know how to find the path from root to a given node but not between 2 random nodes.

Comment: If you are asking a question about algorithms, then tag as such (and neither C nor C++ are appropriate tags). Otherwise, you should generally only tag the language you are compiling, as C and C++ can be very different when asking about implementation details.

Comment: did my posts answer your question? can you elaborate on where you're struck otherwise, e.g. post some code to show what you tried already, especially how you identify your nodes (how you find the root-path).

Comment: find LCA and compute path from LCA to both the nodes

Answer (score 4):

you can take the two paths from the root to the two nodes and remove the common sub-path.

```
         1
        /
       2
      /
     3
   /   \
  4     7
 / \   / \
5   6 8   9
```

e.g. for the path from `5` to `9` in the example you'd get the two paths
`1 2 3 4 5` and `1 2 3 7 9` and
would find `3` to be the lowest common parent node. then reverse the path starting in `5` up to the common parent and append the rest in the path to `9`: `5 4` + `3` + `7 9` -> `5 4 3 7 9`

Comment: what if it was not a binary tree but a normal tree with not numbers values in it but some color just like red black tree? @BeyelerStudios

Comment: @ShefaliChaudhary same approach as long as you can search for a root-path

Comment: well but it isn't working in the case if we have a tree where root node is black and every black node has a red child and every red node has a black child and if we have to find no of black node btw 4th to 5th node then it gets difficult to find common path same for other nodes as well like 3 and 4. @   BeyelerStudios

Comment: @ShefaliChaudhary how would you identify the different nodes in your example? you have to be able to identify your nodes to find a root-path - the identifier doesn't have to be an integer, it might not even be comparable, but every node has to be uniquely identifiable (you can always brute-force search the root-path).

Comment: Why did you write your tree differently than in the OP?

Comment: @0x499602D2 because this example shows two important parts of this approach: firstly reduction of a common subpath `1 2 3` and secondly the inversion of the rest `4 5`